# Programmatically helping NAT Translation

Tags: ajax, nat

I have a scenario where I have multiple mobile phones using a single home wifi router (read not special or expensive) When I get the phones to send almost identical requests to the same location the router appears to be dropping one phone and keeping the other (generally the faster of the two).

After testing for a while now, I'm closing in on the hypothesis that NAT translation is blocking one of the phones or dropping its returned info from the web.

The goal is to get both phones to communicate with a web application online through a generic home wifi without (key aspect here) modifying the router.

My communication is an AJAX request from within a PhoneGap application. Is there something that I can do programatically to help NAT work it's magic and support multiple phones?

Comment: This just sounds broken.  If your router is working correctly, NAT shouldn't be "dropping" anything.

Comment: That was my first thought, but this has now been tested on 6 different routers. All of them displaying the same effect.

Comment: I guess this is going to be brand-specific if at all possible. What router is it?

Comment: Most testing has happened on BT HomeHub 3 (No idea what underlying brand they are). But we've also tried on Linksys router, BT Fusion, BT HomeHub 4, and BT Business Hub 3.

Comment: I can't think of any cause that has anything to do with NAT.  A much more plausible explanation would be that e.g. the server refuses to honour two parallel requests from the same IP.

Comment: That's the last test I need to make I've just moved to a new web host and I'm waiting for domain name to change over to do the testing. Over the last few months though the web host people have swore up and down it wasn't their server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an unknown issue with the Web Host provider. Despite more than a dozen detailed requests for what on their side was blocking things I was always referred to how my own equipment or own code was at fault.

Set myself up a VPS and presto change-o I have a working system with no modifications to the code or the equipment.

TIL I don't like people who cover up their incompetency by blaming others.

Comment: Five Identical answers all saying it was the fault of the hosting provider?

Comment: Over the period of about a year and a half I dealt with what turned out to be a hosting provider issue. And all questions I asked pertaining to this issue had one root cause. I could have left it blank or this boiler plate in. My thinking was that this answer might help someone else to attempt a second host if faced with a similar situation.

Comment: Valid argument and in the circumstances, a helpful choice. Apologies but it looked like someone just deciding to close all their open questions with boilerplate.